# Jboss with Hotswap Agent using Jboss Modules

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, hotswap

Hello Everyone! 
              I'm deploying a multi-module project on JBoss and with the help of [HotswapAgent](http://hotswapagent.org/index.html)( [GitHub](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent) ) and DCEVM.

The Problem is that the deployment loads with hotswap-agent but it doesn't reload the classes when I perform any changes!

I read the configuration for JBOSS modules in HA-Agent : [Configuration](http://hotswapagent.org/mydoc_plugin_jbossmodules.html)

but I can't seem to understand the following:

> Add extraClassPath from hotswap-agent.properties to org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader, so that all application servers (JBossAS, WildFly) based on jboss’s module classloader can use HotswapAgent’s extraClassPath

I mean as in I added extraclass path properties to my HA-properties files but how do I transfer them to **org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader**.

Also if there is any other cause that might be preventing HotswapAgent from reloading classes in JBoss then do tell me! As all plugins load correctly but when I make changes ( In intelli J using HA plugin ) and build the class after changes then I get no message from HA in the console that the class has been reloaded nor does it show any effects from the changes.

Comment: Did you try to follow [Intellij IDEA setup
](http://hotswapagent.org/mydoc_setup_intellij_idea.html) after that it worked for me

Comment: @wirnse yeps! the Intelli-J plugin is live!

Comment: Do you start wildfly in debug mode and do you deploy the application exploded? After that when i hit `ctrl + shift + F9` class gets compiles and hot swaped

Comment: Ctrl+F9 Yes.

But I found the root of the problem, the proxies required by hotswap-agent for my spring classes aren't being constructed so that's why it gave me a warning that it's not going to read the classes. 

I opened the issue on their github : https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/275